# Migration from 2010 to 2013 issue

Tags: 2013, 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, migration

In my company we have a site working under SharePoint 2010. This site contains some custom templates with custom web parts.

Actually we have to migrate to SharePoint 2013. So i have created the environment, web application, as usually do. But when i try to create the site collection from the 2010 template, i got this issue:

> Sorry, something went wrong
>
> The source was not found, but some or all
>   event logs could not be searched.  To create the source, you need
>   permission to read all event logs to make sure that the new source
>   name is unique.  Inaccessible logs: Security.

No other specifications were given. Right now we are blocked, and unable to fix from where we should start.
If Some genius people would give me a solution, suggestion, or even an advice, i will be grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the templates references are pointing to the 15 hive. I faced the same kind of issue due to this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how can i change this reference ?

Comment: Just open the templates and check for the "~/_controltemplates/" or ~/layouts and add "15/" to it like "~/_controltemplates/" to "~/_controltemplates/15/"

Answer (score -2):

Solved this by copying (SP2010) \14\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES to (SP2013) \14\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES.

Comment: Please provide more details.